# PHP: Why do two class instances share same data?

Tags: php, oop

Good morning,

I appear to be codeblind for my own code so I'd like to ask for some extra eyes and advice on a piece of code if written some weeks ago.

**The Code** (shortened)

```
class TrackingCostCollection {
  private $available=0;
  private $ordered=0;
  private $differenceNumKits=0;

  public function fill ($row) {
    ...
  }

  /**
  * @var TrackingCostCollection $collection
  */
  public function merge ($collection) {

    $this->available += $collection->available;
    $this->ordered += $collection->ordered;
    $this->differenceNumKits= $this->available-$this->ordered;
  }
}
```

**The Problem**

When iterating and grouping data by one of the data fields I encounter the problem that two different class instances stored inside two different arrays contain the same data although I don't see why? As soon as I use an extra "clone" the problem disappears but I want to learn why my code behaves the way it does:

```
foreach ($arrValues as $row) {
  ...
  $this->calculateStatistics($row);

}


private function calculateStatistics ($row) {
  $fieldValue= $row['country'];
  $collection = new TrackingCostCollection();
  $collection->fill($row);

  if (!isset($this->arrStatistics[$fieldValue])) {
    $this->arrStatistics[$fieldValue] = $collection2;
  } else {
    /* @var TrackingCostCollection $previousCollection2 */
    $previousCollection = $this->arrStatistics[$fieldValue];
    $previousCollection->merge($collection2);
    $this->arrStatistics[$fieldValue] = $previousCollection;
    unset($previousCollection);
  }

  // using $collection instead of $collection2 will cause 
  // two array entries containing the same data

  $collection2= clone $collection;
  if (!isset($this->arrTotals[$fieldValue])) {
    $this->arrTotals[$fieldValue] = $collection2;
  } else {
    /* @var TrackingCostCollection $previousCollection2 */
    $previousCollection = $this->arrTotals[$fieldValue];
    $previousCollection->merge($collection2);
    $this->arrTotals[$fieldValue] = $previousCollection;
    unset($previousCollection);
  }
}
```

If more code is necessary to diagnose the cause of the problem just let me know and I'll add more.

Thanks a lot in advance for your time!

Comment: because of the clone, clone returns a copy of $collection and assign it to $collection2

Comment: By default objects are defined by reference in PHP.

Comment: Use the __clone() callback to get around this problem; it's like the other commenters mention

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment and had forgotten that I stored the same pointer to the $collection object in both arrays causing the duplication. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit to not having gone through your code in any detail, but I suppose you're having a problem with this:

> [...] an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value [...]. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables [...] hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

If you want to make two independent copies of an object, you need to `clone` it. If you don't, you're passing around the same object and modifications to it will be visible to anyone who was passed this object. E.g.:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->foo = 'bar';

function modify(stdClass $obj) {
    $obj->foo = 'baz';
}

modify($obj);

echo $obj->foo; // baz
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to the OOP manual section, now I got it. I was puzzled because I thought that I didn't modify the $collection variable at all but I totally forgot that I stored the pointer to the $collection object inside both $this->arrTotals and $this->arrStatistics so that's what caused the problem.